# Use dynamic class name in private static final variable of a class

Tags: java, reflection, static

Consider and example as below:

```
public class LoggerTestClass {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LoggerTestClass.class);
}
```

In above example parameter passed to `getLogger` method is hard coded i.e `LoggerTestClass.class`
Now every time I change the class name I have to change the `getLogger` method's parameter.

Any other way which will fetch the class name automatically, for example for non static variable we can add `this.getClass()`

Comment: if you are using an IDE and choose refactor -> rename instead of just manually renaming, that should be done automatically

Comment: Not completely helpful but can work. @Stultuske thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use java 9+? Then solution is pretty simple:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
```

As `MethodHandles.lookup()` creates lookup using caller class. (via `Reflection.getCallerClass()` but `Reflection` is internal API, so you need that additional method handle lookup step)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to achive it in a clean fashion. All you need to do is to put `@Log` on top of your class and it will give you a `log` object to work with.
Read more [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/log)

Answer (score 1):

Bro,For the question,first of all,we need make clear some concept.

In java,if a identifier is a member of a class,and decorated by 'static' keyword,it's value is Decided in the compile phase.

If the 'final' keyword is added,the identifier is constant,it's value must have a initial value on it is declared.and the value can't be change in the java runtime.

And the interesting thing is, the static constent is only declared inside the class,it can be called 'Classname' + '.' ,but has no connection to the class context.**if there's no context ,the identifier con't become dynamic.**

I think if let the identifier become dynamic ,there are only two ways:

1. let the identifier become a variable.remove the 'final' key word.the code look like this:

   ```
   class Test {

       private static Logger LOGGER;

       public Test() {
           LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getSimpleName());
       }

   }
   ```

   The 'private' keyword is sufficient if you don't want other classes to access it.
2. **Try the java dynamic proxy. it can change the class in java runtime.**

Code happy ~

Welcome to talk with me~